# Storage Access Framework deleteDocument

Tags: android, android-storage

I just try to delete a file using Storage Access Framework however deleteDocument always returns false. I have a Asus zenfone 5 with Android 5.0
I just wonder if the contentprovider and uri is correct or not. The uri is a path from SDCard(/storage/MicroSD/test123123.apk)

```
String t = "";
void deleteFunc(String filepath) {
     t = filepath;
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE");
     intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Toast.makeText(this, "S: " + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "D: " + t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            DocumentFile test = DocumentFile.fromFile(new File(t));

            DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(t));
            Toast.makeText(this, "P: " + test.delete(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "T: " + DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(t)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

---

Here it is the exception from deleteDocument

```
09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents: Failed to delete document
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.provider.DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(DocumentsContract.java:987)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.provider.DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(DocumentsContract.java:971)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at com.test.example.ResultActivity.onActivityResult(SourceFile:364)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6177)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3551)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3598)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:147)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    09-23 11:46:13.054  8216  8216 W Documents:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Why do you let the user pick a document with `OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` ? And after that you throw the data intent and hence the picked uri away and use some file path and try to create a DocumentFile from that file path? All makes no sense. You should use the picked urii instead. `test==null` if you wonder why you have a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Moreover with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` you would pick a 'directory' tree.` I suggest you to read some posts with tag `storage-access-framework`.

Comment: I just want to get delete right in whole SD card. Then I am going to delete any file I want. Is it possible ?

Comment: You did not react on all the things i said. You should start with reacting. For the rest your words are very unclear.

Comment: The thing I want to do it just single document deletion. If I am gonna achieve that goal, everything will possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used Uri.parse(t) while SAF has its own document addressing system. You cannot map filepath to SAF tree unless doing some custom mapping.

Here is the code in Xamarin:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
            if (requestCode == SRC_URI_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var androidUri = data.Data;
                var storageUri = DocumentsContract.BuildDocumentUriUsingTree(androidUri, DocumentsContract.GetTreeDocumentId(androidUri));
            }
    }
```

Now you need to traverse storageUri and get children URI using DocumentsContract.BuildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree and ContentResolver.Query.